# c# replicating button click with javascript injection

Tags: javascript, c#, html, javascript-injection

Hello I want to replicate some button click on site

Button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs" onclick="getComponents('188855', '5a0f44a9d70380.12406536');return false;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewMtComponents">View</button>
```

what this does is opens popup window on current page and display some data(which is not loaded with html file)

This is my code for injection:

```
public void inject(string a , string b)
    {
        HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement script = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)script.DomElement;
        element.text = "getComponents('" + a + "', '" + b + "');";
        head.AppendChild(script);
    }
```

But it does absolutely nothing. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to append the script.
You can use the InvokeScript method as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Object[] args = new Object[2];
args[0] = (Object)a;
args[1] = (Object)b;
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("getComponents", args);
```

Comment: I tried to ran same code in chrome developer console and it gives me some error. It's javascript issue.